# Could not setcwd() (errno 2: No such file or directory) om Mac OS 12

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I am trying to add the gradle wrapper. So while running

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 2.0
```

ima getting an error

- What went wrong:
  Could not set process working directory to '/Users/amoriodi/.gradle/daemon/7.2': could not setcwd() (errno 2: No such file or directory)

stacktrace is the following:

```
    * Exception is:
net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not set process working directory to '/Users/amoriodi/.gradle/daemon/7.2': could not setcwd() (errno 2: No such file or directory)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcess.setWorkingDirectory(DefaultProcess.java:52)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcess.setWorkingDirectory(WrapperProcess.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.processenvironment.NativePlatformBackedProcessEnvironment.setNativeProcessDir(NativePlatformBackedProcessEnvironment.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.processenvironment.AbstractProcessEnvironment.setProcessDir(AbstractProcessEnvironment.java:81)
        at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.processenvironment.AbstractProcessEnvironment.maybeSetProcessDir(AbstractProcessEnvironment.java:89)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:88)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: Does that directory exist? (Careful, because one path item starting with a dot means it should be invisible).

Comment: yeah, look
```➜ ~ cd /Users/amoriodi/.gradle/daemon/7.2
➜  7.2 ```